# Getting mount type information in python on OSX

Tags: python, macos, mount

Is there a way in which I can get some information about the mounts I have in the folder `/Volumes` in OSX?

I want to be able to tell the difference between disk images like dmgs and other types, like hard disks or network mounts.

I tried parsing the output of `mount -v` and looking if `read-only` is in the line but I doubt that's a particularly accurate way of telling, and also not a good method either.

Is there any module or method that will give me this information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the `diskutil(8)` and `hdiutil(1)` tools.

Comment: Ah thanks, I looked at `diskutil info [mount_name]` but this is a bit slow. So instead went for `diskutil list` and all the hdd seem to be on `/dev/disk0` and other disk images are on different disks, and other types of mounts dont appear. This seems to be a good enough solution